# SpectroVis spectrophotometer values changing after pulling cuvette out

Tags: kinetics

I am required to write a research paper for school in a specific subject and I have chosen to write mine in chemistry.
I am investigating the kinetics of the Briggs-Rauscher oscillating reaction.
I am using a spectrophotometer to take samples of the reactants and determine the absorbance at 460nm every 45 seconds to calculate the rate at which iodine is produced.
However, I am using a spectrovis spectrophotometer, who's calibration values change without me doing anything and sometimes do not register the fact that iodine concentration has increased. Is there anyway I can fix this problem and prevent the readings from changing?

Comment: One should be there to see exactly what is going on. Are you following the reaction in the cuvette or just taking sample at regular interval? By the way I try to find an answer that migh help you and can be done in parallel.  Comparing the two might really makes a great paper. .....

Comment: Here it is. Get a decent baseline and do both. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112263/taking-kinetic-readings-for-the-briggs-rauscher-oscillating-reaction/112276#112276

Comment: "However, I am using a spectrovis spectrophotometer, who's calibration values change without me doing anything and sometimes do not register the fact that iodine concentration has increased." Please share an example of the data. What is the meaning of "calibration values change"?  Are you putting the cuvet  properly each time i.e. the transparent side is in the light beam path?